# uglifyjs command permission denied

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, file-permissions, permission-denied, uglifyjs2

I have a strange problem about my uglifyjs command.

The uglifyjs file looks like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/node
// -*- js -*-

"use strict";

require("../tools/exit");

var fs = require("fs");
var info = require("../package.json");
```

And when Apache run it under its user (daemon), I got permission denied error in the PHP log.

```
/usr/bin/env: /usr/local/bin/node: Permission denied
```

I checked those file permissions and all users have read and run permission.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 May 13  2019 /usr/local/bin/node -> /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 29851602 Jul 11  2017 /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 28880 Aug  1  2018 /usr/bin/env
```

I am using AWS EC2 server.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: I used nvm to install nodejs and I just updated the nodejs to latest version and he error is still there. Maybe this is because of the nvm?

Comment: After some tests, I found that just this command is permission denied. "sh: /usr/local/bin/node: Permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on node_modules.

Give permission to current user:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```